# For loop won't work in creating multiple rectangles in Adobe Animate CC

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, jquery-animate, adobe, easeljs

I am using Adobe Animate CC (formerly Flash Professional CC) and I'm trying to adjust the following code snippet so that it creates multiple rectangles.

```
var shape = new createjs.Shape(new createjs.Graphics().beginFill("#ff0000").drawRect(5,5,100,100));
this.addChild(shape);
```

I've then adjusted this and put it in a for loop which I thought would work in replicating the object. The following code only creates one rectangle?

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var i = new createjs.Shape(new createjs.Graphics().beginFill("#ff0000").drawRect(5,5,30,30));
    this.addChild(i);

    // Move object so that they don't lie on top of each other
    this.x += 50;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

I assume you are extending `Container` so you can add children to it. This is why you use `this.addChild()` instead of something like `stage.addChild()`, right?

1. You are overwriting your iterator variable `i` when you create your shape. I recommend a different name, like `square` or `child`.
2. You are incrementing the `x` position of `this`, so it will add all your squares at the same position, and then just move your container by 50px. All the children will still be on top of each other. You should change this to `child.x`.
3. Once you do that, it will still not work because you are incrementing each shape from `0` to `50` - so they will all be on top of each other still. Change this to something like `child.x = i * 50`.

Here is a code snippet.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var child = new createjs.Shape(new createjs.Graphics().beginFill("#ff0000").drawRect(5,5,30,30));
    this.addChild(child);

    // Move object so that they don't lie on top of each other
    child.x = i * 50;
}
```

Here is a quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/vphj9qL0/

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Lanny. Yes that was what I was after. I appreciate your time in answering with great explanation.